# Performing update and delete operations with dropdown-list

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express

I do it by typing the ids while updating or inserting the room information.
but it doesn't make sense to show id to the user. so I want to select the name of the dormitory over the id with dropdown.//////////////////////////////////////////

```
const client = require('../../db')
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json()); //req.body

app.listen(2906, ()=>{
    console.log("Sever is now listening at port 5000");
})

client.connect();


app.get('/rooms', (req, res)=>{
    client.query(`Select * from rooms`, (err, result)=>{
        if(!err){
            res.send(result.rows);
        }
    });
   
})



app.get('/rooms/:roomid', (req, res)=>{
    client.query(`Select * from rooms where roomid=${req.params.roomid}`, (err, result)=>{
        if(!err){
            res.send(result.rows);
        }
    });
   
})


const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.post('/rooms', (req, res)=> {
    const rooms = req.body;
    let insertQuery = `insert into rooms(dormitoryid ,capacity ,wc,price,roomno) values(
        '${rooms.dormitoryid}', 
        '${rooms.capacity}', 
        '${rooms.wc}',
        '${rooms.price}',
        '${rooms.roomno}')`

    client.query(insertQuery, (err, result)=>{
        if(!err){
            res.send('Insertion was successful')
        }
        else{ console.log(err.message) }
    })
  
})


app.put('/rooms/:roomid', (req, res)=> {
    let rooms = req.body;
    let updateQuery = `update rooms set 
    dormitoryid= '${rooms.dormitoryid}',
    capacity= '${rooms.capacity}',
    wc= '${rooms.wc}',
    price= '${rooms.price}',
    roomno='${rooms.roomno}' 
    where roomid = ${req.params.roomid}`

    client.query(updateQuery, (err, result)=>{
        if(!err){
            res.send('Update was successful')
        }
        else{ console.log(err.message) }
    })
    client.end;
    })

app.delete('/rooms/:roomid', (req, res)=> {
    const rooms = req.body;
    let insertQuery = `delete from rooms where roomid=${req.params.roomid}`

    client.query(insertQuery, (err, result)=>{
        if(!err){
            res.send('Deletion was successful')
        }
        else{ console.log(err.message) }
    })
    
})
```

This is my database code.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const AddDormitory = () => {

  const [nameofdormitory, setNameofdormitory] = useState("");
  const [locationid, setLocationid] = useState("");
  const [typeofdormitory ,setTypeofdormitory] = useState("");
  const [capacity, setCapacity] = useState("");
  const [checkintime, setCheckintime] = useState("");
  const [checkouttime, setCheckouttime] = useState("");
  const [numberofmeals, setNumberofmeals] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");

  const AddDormitory = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const body = {nameofdormitory,locationid,typeofdormitory,capacity,checkintime,checkouttime,numberofmeals,phone};
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:2103/dormitory1", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
      });

      
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
    <body><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous"></link>
         <div className="mb-3 ">
          <form action="">
            <div className="form-row mx-auto">
              <div className="col col-lg-3">
                <input
                  value={nameofdormitory}
                  onChange={(e) => setNameofdormitory(e.target.value)}
                  className="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="nameofdormitory"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col col-lg-3">
                <input
                  value={locationid}
                  onChange={(e) => setLocationid(e.target.value)}
                  className="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="locationid"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col col-lg-3">
                <input
                  value={typeofdormitory}
                  onChange={(e) => setTypeofdormitory(e.target.value)}
                  className="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="typeofdormitory"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col col-lg-3">
                <input
                  value={capacity}
                  onChange={(e) => setCapacity(e.target.value)}
                  className="form-control"
                  type="number"
                  placeholder="capacity"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col col-lg-3">
                <input
                  value={checkintime}
                  onChange={(e) => setCheckintime(e.target.value)}
                  className="form-control"
                  type="time"
                  placeholder="checkintime"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col col-lg-3">
                <input
                  value={checkouttime}
                  onChange={(e) => setCheckouttime(e.target.value)}
                  className="form-control"
                  type="time"
                  placeholder="checkouttime"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col col-lg-3">
                <input
                  value={numberofmeals}
                  onChange={(e) => setNumberofmeals(e.target.value)}
                  className="form-control"
                  type="number"
                  placeholder="numberofmeals"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col col-lg-3">
                <input
                  value={phone}
                  onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)}
                  className="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="phone"
                />
              </div>
              
             
              
              <button
                onClick={AddDormitory}
                type="submit"
                className="btn btn-primary"
              >
                Add
              </button>
             
            </div>
          </form>
         
        </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default AddDormitory
```

my code where i add room

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const UpdateRooms = ({rooms}) => {
  const [dormitoryid, setDormitoryid] = useState(rooms.dormitoryid);
  const [capacity, setCapacity] = useState(rooms.capacity);
  const [wc, setWc] = useState(rooms.wc);
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(rooms.price);
  const [roomno, setRoomno] = useState(rooms.roomno);
  
  const UpdateValues = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const body = { dormitoryid,capacity,wc,price,roomno};
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:2906/rooms/${rooms.roomid}`,
        {
          method: "PUT",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          body: JSON.stringify(body)
        }
      );


    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };



  return (
    <>
   <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-warning"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target={`#id${rooms.roomid}`}
      >
        Edit
      </button>

      
      <div
        class="modal"
        id={`id${rooms.roomid}`}
        onClick={() => {setDormitoryid(rooms.dormitoryid)}}
        
      >
         <div
        class="modal1"
        id={`id${rooms.roomid}`}
        onClick={() => {setCapacity(rooms.capacity)}}
        
      >

      </div>
      <div
        class="modal2"
        id={`id${rooms.roomid}`}
        onClick={() => {setWc(rooms.wc)}}
        
      >
        
      </div>
       <div
        class="modal3"
        id={`id${rooms.roomid}`}
        onClick={() => {setPrice(rooms.price)}}
        
      >
       <div
        class="modal4"
        id={`id${rooms.roomid}`}
        onClick={() => {setRoomno(rooms.roomno)}}
        
      >

      </div>
      </div>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Location</h4>
              <button
                type="button"
                class="close"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                onClick={() => setDormitoryid(rooms.dormitoryid)}
              >
               
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                class="close"
                data-dismiss="modal1"
                onClick={() => setCapacity(rooms.capacity)}
              >
               
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                class="close"
                data-dismiss="modal2"
                onClick={() => setWc(rooms.wc)}
              >
               
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                class="close"
                data-dismiss="modal3"
                onClick={() => setPrice(rooms.price)}
              >
               
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                class="close"
                data-dismiss="modal4"
                onClick={() => setRoomno(rooms.roomno)}
              >
               
              </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                value={dormitoryid}
                onChange={e => setDormitoryid(e.target.value)}
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                value={capacity}
                onChange={e => setCapacity(e.target.value)}
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                value={wc}
                onChange={e => setWc(e.target.value)}
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                value={price}
                onChange={e => setPrice(e.target.value)}
              />
               <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                value={roomno}
                onChange={e => setRoomno(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-warning"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                onClick={e => UpdateValues(e)}
              >
                Edit
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-danger"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                onClick={() => (setDormitoryid(rooms.dormitoryid),setCapacity(rooms.capacity),setWc(rooms.wc),setPrice(rooms.price),setRoomno(rooms.roomno))}
              >
                Close
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </>
  )
}

export default UpdateRooms
```

my code where i update room

[website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2bxV.png)

Comment: Your question is not clear. please add more info.

Comment: @XPD sorry, I added a photo named website link to the question. While I am adding, I want to write the name of the dormitory belonging to that id, not the id of the dormitory. so when I type "dalarlar" instead of typing "id", let it be registered in the database

Comment: For that try, [auto increment](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_using_autoincrement.htm) for the database and then you dont need to send id with the post data. You can then add another text box to add the name.